# Google chart displays briefly then disappears

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-visualization

I have attached my HTML code.  This worked fine yesterday and over the last 8 months.  I know google has updated charts August 17 but cant find anything as per those updates.

The chart displays briefly when you first connect to the page but goes away. This issue is affecting my Apple, Ubuntu, Windows laptop and desktop pointing to something web bound.

```
    <head> 


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript"> 


// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package. 

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']}); 

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded. 

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); 


function drawChart() { 

var json = $.ajax({ 

url: "get_json.php", // make this url point to the data file 

dataType: "json", 

async: false 

}).responseText; 


// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server. 

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json); 

var options = { 

title: 'TODAYS  CHART ', 

legend: { position: 'bottom' }, 

colors: ['blue', 'green', 'red'], 

is3D: 'true', 

fontSize: 16, 

fontName: 'Telex', 

vAxis: {title: "Usage",titleTextStyle:{ fontName: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', bold: true , italic: false, fontSize: 16, color:'#666666'}, gridlines:{count: 15}}, 

hAxis: {title: "Easter Standard Time", format: '', titleTextStyle:{ fontName: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', bold: true , italic: false, fontSize: 16, color:'#666666'}, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:45, gridlines:{count: 24}}, 

width:1100, 

height: 500, 

pointSize: 7, 


}; 

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options. 

//do not forget to check ur div ID 

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 

chart.draw(data, options); 



setInterval(drawChart, 500 ); 

} 


    </script> 



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css"> 

    <link href="page_css/......"> 

    <style type="text/css"> 


.current_container 
{ 
            float:left; position: relative; margin-left: 35px; width: 1100px; top: 10px; height: 400px; text-align:center;
}


     </style>

     </head>

      <body>


     <div class="current_container">
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 650px; position: inherit; float: none"></div>

     </div>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you may need to move to the frozen version, see instructions here https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-visualization-api/XxP1zYbWQRE https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-visualization-api/hBCwxtXYNZ8

Comment: google.charts.load("41",{'packages':['corechart']});

                        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                        function drawChart() {
                                var json = $.ajax({
                                        url: "get_json.php", // make this url point to the data file
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        async: false
                                }).responseText;

                                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);

Comment: Now nothing displays

Comment: Please note that I am using a line/plot chart

Comment: I copied your code into a live demo site and it worked fine except that it had no data because the dependent data is not available.  Perhaps post an example of the json returned by the ajax call?

Comment: The reason the frozen never worked was due to  my 'setInterval'  I increased the value (doubled) and graph began to work. I would suspect there is a bug with that parameter